# Restructure Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have the following data-frame:

```
grp       dates  count
A    2018-01-01     10
A    2018-01-02     20
A    2018-01-03     25
A    2018-01-04     30
B    2018-01-03     10
B    2018-01-04     30
...
```

However, I'd like to have it in this form:

```
dates        A   B ...
2018-01-01  10  NA
2018-01-02  20  NA
2018-01-03  25  10
2018-01-04  30  30
```

Whats the easiest way to convert it? And which form is better?

```
grp <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B")
count <- c(10, 20, 25, 30, 10, 30)
dates <- c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04")

df <- data.frame(grp, count, dates)
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dates` vector is different from the example data your show, in that it has a duplicated date `2018-01-01`. Assuming that's a mistake, you can do the following:

```r
grp <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B")
count <- c(10, 20, 25, 30, 10, 30)
dates <- c("2018-01-01", "2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04")

df <- data.frame(grp, count, dates)

library(tidyr)
df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = count)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   dates          A     B
#>   <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 2018-01-01    10    NA
#> 2 2018-01-02    20    NA
#> 3 2018-01-03    25    10
#> 4 2018-01-04    30    30
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>